# rsyncing with --files-from and -mtime option downloading old files that are in a newer directory

Tags: find, rsync

I've got the following command to try to sync only files less than about 36 hours old (2200 minutes):

```
sudo su -c "rsync -vrt --delete --rsync-path='sudo rsync' --files-from=<(find '/home/dir1' -mmin -2200 -exec basename {} \;)  '/home/dir1'  Maildir"
```

It works except it's bringing over all the files in some of the subdirectories even if they are older the 36 hours. This is because those subdirectories are younger than 36 hours.

So I modified the `find` commmand in `--files-from` to this:

`find '/home/dir1' -type f -mmin -2200 -exec basename {} \;`

Now I have a new problem. It cannot save the files and fails with many of these errors:

```
rsync: link_stat "/home/dir1/new/blah" failed: No such file or directory (2)
```

Is there a way to fix this besides doing one rsync to create the directories and then another to bring the files over?

Comment: You should change the title so that it relates your actual current problem. Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636889/rsync-how-can-i-configure-it-to-create-target-directory-on-server

Comment: Well, I'm trying to show what I did to try to fix the original problem. Maybe there is a different approach then what I tried.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after fiddling with this and patching together different suggestions from elsewhere, I came up with this:

```
sudo su -c "rsync -vrt --delete --from0 --files-from=<(cd /home/dir; find . -type f -mmin -2200 -print0 )  '/home/dir1'  Maildir"
```

This will `cd` into the source directory first before running the `find` command. I also use `-print0` argument to the find command instead of `-exec basename {}` and add a `--from0` argument to rsync which allow it to parse the null-character-terminated output of the find command.

Comment: There's a `;` missing before `find` and `--print0` should be `-print0`. I believe you can also remove option `--rsync-path`.

Comment: Fixed. The --rsync-path option can be removed in this case where the transfer is happening on the same machine, yes. Might be needed if you are running a similar command to this on a remote machine.